# How should you use fields in a child class JS?

Tags: javascript, class

When I declare fields in the child class, and then access them with `this` it breaks.
I have tried the big arrow

This is a simplified example example

```
class Shape
{
  
}

class Polygon: Shape {
  name;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Polygon';
  }

  cout()
  {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
  
}

const poly1 = new Polygon();

poly1.cout(); // returns an error
// Expected output: "Polygon"
```

Edit:

```
class TankScene extends Scene
{
    tank1;
    collidables;

    buildScene()
    {
        super.buildScene();
        this.collidables = [];

        this.tank1 = new ControllableTank(SpriteTypes.blueTank);
        this.floor = new GameObject("Floor", ModelTypes.plane, SpriteTypes.woodenFloor);


        this.tank1.tankBody.uniformSetScale(5);
        this.floor.uniformSetScale(10);

        this.collidables.push(this.tank1.tankBody);

        this.addChild(this.tank1);
        this.addChild(this.floor);

        this.tank1.setCollidables(this.collidables);
    }

    doUpdate() {
        super.doUpdate();
        console.log(this.tank1);
    }

}
```

This is my actual code. The log statement at the end returns the expected value when the fields are not declared, though when I declare `tank1` and `collidables` then it breaks. What is wrong?

Comment: The error you get should tell you exactly what to do: you have to call `super();` in the subclass constructor before you start setting properties of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Shape
{
  
}

class Polygon extends Shape {
  name;
  constructor() {
      super();
    this.name = 'Polygon';
  }

  cout()
  {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
  
}

const poly1 = new Polygon();

poly1.cout();
```

You are not extending Shape properly

Comment: I am a muppet...